# Using # to mark end of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am currently studying another user’s code for a coding question from LeetCode. My question is about certain aspects of his code. Here’s a link to [the question](https://leetcode.com/problems/summary-ranges/).

### Question:

Why does this user use a `#` to mark the end of the array?

Under the second `if` case, the user writes:

```
ans.push(nums[t] + '->' + (nums[i-1]))
```

Now, I understand what this statement does. My question is: Why does this produce an output of `["0->2",...]` instead of `[0"->"2,...]`?

```
var summaryRanges = function(nums) {
    var t = 0
    var ans = []
    nums.push('#')
    for(var i=1;i<nums.length;i++)
        if(nums[i]-nums[t] !== i-t){
            if(i-t>1)
                ans.push(nums[t]+'->'+(nums[i-1]))
            else
                ans.push(nums[t].toString())
            t = i
        }
    return ans
}
```

Comment: `nums[t] + '->' + (nums[i-1])` is string concatenation. `0 + "X" = "0X"`

Comment: It’s impossible to produce `0"->"2`, as that’s a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm depends on that the difference between `nums[i]` and `nums[t]` is not the same as the difference between `i` and `t`. When that happens, the algorithm adds more to the output. This creates a special case when the last range is just a single number, since this cannot trigger the condition.

Hence the hash character is padding to extend the array in order to make the algorithm work, so that the condition `nums[i]-nums[t] !== i-t` will trigger even for a finishing range of a single number. It could be any string really as long as it is not an integer number.